# Cannot properly navigate between two different stacks in react native and keep back functionallity

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Currently these are my screens in my react native app.

```
Root Nav - (SwitchNavigator)
    Stack A - (BottomTabNavigator)
        Page A
        Page B
    Stack B - (StackNavigator)
        Page C
        Page D
```

I am trying to navigate to page `C/D` From pages `A/B` But when I try to navigate using `this.props.navigation.navigate()` It will navigate correctly, but the history functionality such as swiping right or calling `goBack()` to go to the previous page (in a different stack) does not work.
When navigating to page `D` and swiping right, it goes to page `C` and swiping right again does not do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different stacks are meant to stand on their own, so if what you need is to keep the navigation history between those screens, you have to set them up in the same stack. Stacks can be set up in your flow just like screens, for example, setting up a stack navigator inside a drawer navigator:

```
/**
 * User drawer stack
 */
const DrawerStack = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: {screen: HomeStack}, //HomeStack is a StackNavigator
}, {
    contentComponent: DrawerContainer,
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
});
```

With this rethink what you want your history like. If I understood your use case correctly, you want A/B to share history with C/D, I'd say you need your stack to be like:

```
Root Nav - (SwitchNavigator)
    Stack B - (StackNavigator)
        Stack A - (BottomTabNavigator)
            Page A
            Page B
        Page C
        Page D
```

If you can't do that for some reason, then you will need to capture back presses and swipes manually to do the behavior yourself.

Comment: Thanks so much!!!, Couldn't figure out why it wasn't working but this helped a ton.